# Multiple ManyToManyField usage and table not found

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have the following class decelerations in my models.py :-

```
enter code here

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    current_clubs = models.ManyToManyField('Club',related_name="current")
    previous_clubs = models.ManyToManyField('Club',related_name="previous")

class Club(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    students = models.ManyToManyField('Student',related_name="stud")
```

When I try to view the student or club class from the admin page, (I am able to create and register Student and Club logins but not view them as an admin), I see the following error :-
DatabaseError at /admin/school/Club/1/
Django Version is 1.5.1
Exception Type is DatabaseError
Exception Value is no such table: school_club_students

I am unsure as to why such a table was not created by Django when I created a Club object. If I try to use the admin interface to add a Club, I run into the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py syncdb`?

Comment: Have you Check tables exist in database?